# Sending powershell commands to Azure vm through CloudShell

Tags: powershell, azure

Using Azure CloudShell I want to send PowerShell commands to a VM that I created. These would be, for example, to add windows features, change AD users, change IIS configuration etc.

I know these can be done by RDPing to the machine or potentially connecting from PowerShell client (for example from within the same network) but I need to do it through CloudShell